Securely Fetching and Caching Polygons in Next.js for Map Rendering
Using Next.js, I want to implement the best practice for fetching polygons and displaying them on a map, while ensuring that the user is unable to see the data in the network tab.
I have tried using getServerSideProps and found that on the initial load, there is nothing visible in the network tab. However, the problem arises when the user changes parameters on the page - I need to find a solution to fetch the data again without exposing it in the network tab or any other browser sources.
What is the best practice to solve this problem? I'm looking for a solution that keeps the data hidden from the user, even when refetching is required due to parameter changes.
I appreciate you taking the time to rephrase the question in a better way.
I have tried different ways. But at the end while fetching data on changing parameters the data will be shown inside the network tab.

Impossible. Whatever data you transfer between the server and the browser, the user will be able to see.

And even the server-side props data will be visible to the user, you just don't see a separate request for it.
